# Travelling by Greyhound for the first time

Tags: new-york-city, greyhound

We will be travelling in September 2017 by Greyhound from New York City to Buffalo with no transfers. The tickets are already booked online. Our departure time is 8.00 am from the Port Authority. We will have 2 checked baggages. How do we find the gate number when we reach the Port Authority terminal?

Comment: @GayotFow things must have changed quite a bit since the last time I took a bus from Port Authority.  Twenty to thirty minutes seems plenty to me.

Comment: @GayotFow probably around the same time.  It was maybe 30 years ago, though, so I don't remember for certain.  (That's the last time I took a long-distance bus from there, which I did maybe a dozen times at various times of day; more recently I've only taken suburban buses to New Jersey on the weekend.)